# Как инициализировать базу данных начальными значениями при первом старте приложения?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Я использую Spring Data + MongoDB.

При первом запуске приложения нужно инициализировать базу данных начальными значениями. Например, добавить в базу основные роли и профили админов системы.

Если делать это на уровне приложения (файл data.sql или @PostConstruct),то это будет не безопасно, мне кажется, потому что будет место, где пароль хранится не в зашифрованном виде.

Добавить данные в базу вручную нельзя, мне кажется, потому что пароли при добавлении в базу должны шифроваться, а это делается на уровне приложения.

Какие есть способы инициализации базы данных начальными значениями при первом запуске приложения на реальном сервере?

Comment: шифруете пароль, берите значение и добавьте в файл data.sql. там уже будет зашифрованный пароль, который уже безопасен

Comment: Сринг дата здесь не при чем, нужно писать специальный аудинтефикатор, который берет
данные из безопасного места. Способов реализации   много, но вы не пробовали писать сами. В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: системы миграции типа flyway и им подобные вполне могут выполнять такие скрипты. на реальных серверах это может быть задачей для cicd